# How to Perform CRUD operation in TableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have written code for performing Delete,Insert,Update . when I execute my code I'm getting an Error like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView. Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row. Please use the category on NSIndexPath in NSIndexPath+UIKitAdditions.h if possible."
I'm adding the code here

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var Insert: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var txtfield: UITextField!
var index = IndexPath()
var models = ["1.Audi","2.Hyundai","3.Bentley","4.Chevrolet","5.Dodge","6.Electric","7.Ford","8.Genesis","9.Honda","10.Ferrari","11.Nissan","12.Porche","13.Range Rover","14.Lamborgini","15.McLaren","16.koneisegg","17.Volvo","18.Mazda","19.Bmw"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
   
}

@IBAction func textFieldEdit(_ sender: UITextField) {
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as? UITableViewCell{
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.txtfield.text
        
    }
}


@IBAction func insertBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let txt = txtfield.text, !txt.isEmpty{
        //self.models.append(txt)
        self.models.insert(txt,at: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        print (models.count)
    }
    
    }

}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        models.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath
    self.txtfield.text = models[indexPath.row]
    
}
}
```

[ScreenShot of My storyBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WroEz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain ***when*** you're getting the error.

Running your code as-is, no apparent errors.

However, my guess is that you're hitting an issue when you haven't yet selected a row, or when you've done something to change the selection while editing in the text field.

Try changing your `textFieldEdit` func to this:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEdit(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // make sure
    //  a row is selected
    // and
    //  we can get a reference to that cell
    guard let pth = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
          let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: pth)
    else {
            return
    }
    // properly unwrap optional .text property
    let str = sender.text ?? ""
    // update the data
    self.models[pth.row] = str
    // update the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = str
}
```

Comment: Actually my error was when I start typing in the textField ,the above mentioned error occurs. and after I refresh my tabledata then the updated value is getting changed

Comment: now its working fine but when I just type something and pressed Update button *I'm getting the error like Thread 1: "Invalid index path for use with UITableView. Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row. Please use the category on NSIndexPath in NSIndexPath+UIKitAdditions.h if possible."*

Comment: @JestinSaji - you didn't include any code for your "Update" button. Do you want your data to update as the user types? Or, do you only want to update the data (and the table view cell) ***after*** the user taps "Update"?

Answer (score 0):

You've instantiated an `IndexPath` without properties

```
var index = IndexPath()
```

If you refer to it before setting a valid property you'll get that error.

### Possible Solution

```
var index: IndexPath?
```

Use an optional for your index rather than setting an invalid default property. It'll be nil until you assign an instance.

You'll then have to use `index?.` or `if let index = index` when using the property, but it'll be safe.